# Nested UIStackViews do not align. How do I align them?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xcode, uistackview

I want to create a spreadsheet style table with stackviews. However as you can see in the image, columns are not aligned due to previous items being wider. How do ı make sure they are aligned ?

[image]

This is how I create stacks:

```
class MyTableFullScreenViewController: UIViewController {

    var json: JSON?

    @IBOutlet weak var scrollView: UIScrollView!
    @IBOutlet weak var verticalStack: UIStackView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        for i in 0..<json!["Rows"].arrayValue.count{

            let horizontalStack = UIStackView()
            horizontalStack.axis = .Horizontal
            horizontalStack.spacing = 16
            horizontalStack.distribution = .Fill


            for j in 0..<json!["Rows"][i]["Column"].arrayValue.count{
                let innerJson = json!["Rows"][i]["Column"][j]
                switch innerJson["InputType"].intValue{
                case 1:
                    Inputs.Input1(innerJson, parent: horizontalStack, isRepeatable: true)
                case 11:
                    Inputs.Input11(innerJson, parent: horizontalStack, isRepeatable: true)
                case 15:
                    Inputs.Input15(innerJson, parent: horizontalStack, isRepeatable: true)
                default:
                    break
                }
            }

            verticalStack.addArrangedSubview(horizontalStack)

        }

    }


}
```

This is how storyboard is done:
[image]

Comment: Did You check how here work distribution `.FillEqually` (or something like that)?

Comment: Outer stack is .Fill, inner stacks are .FillEqually.

Comment: Wrong tool for the job.  Try a collection view with a custom layout.

Comment: You have any examples of collection view achieving what I need here ?

Comment: CollectionView do it almost automatically, just search.

Answer (score 0):

You should be using a `UICollectionView` as opposed to `UIStackView` for this... Think of UIStackView as a wrapper around AutoLayout simplifying the laying out of a collection of views *within a predefined space* as opposed a *scrollable container* that's able to handle the layout of a virtually infinite number of views.

If you're creating a spreadsheet, you'll likely want the ability to scroll both horizontally and vertically, but you'd only be able to scroll vertically based on the sample code you posted (unless you 'hack' UIStackView but at that point you might as well use a UICollectionView).

What I'd recommend is to create a `UITableView` containing a horizontally scrolling UICollectionView in each cell. Alternatively, depending on your needs, you could also nest the UICollectionViews within a vertically scrolling UICollectionView.

Containing UICollectionViews/UITableViews within other UICollectionViews/UITableViews is actually *very performant* and frequently used in scenarios like the one you described.